# JavaScript get textContent via onclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick

There is my table written with php :

```
$table = "<table>";
$table .=  "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Link</th><th>Öncelik</th><th></th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td class='code'>" . $row["Code"] . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td class='link' contenteditable='true' oninput='showSaveButton(this.parentElement)'>" . $row["Link"] . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td class='priority' contenteditable='true' oninput='showSaveButton(this.parentElement)'>" . $row["Priority"] . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td><button onclick='deleteRow(" . $row["Code"] . ")'>Delete</button></td>";
    $table .= "<td><button hidden=true onclick='saveRow(this.parentElement)' class='save-button'>Save</button></td>";
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
```

scripts:

```
function showSaveButton(row) {
    const saveButton = row.querySelector('.save-button');
    saveButton.hidden = false;
}
```

```
function saveRow(row) {
    const link = row.querySelector('.link').textContent;
    const priority = row.querySelector('.priority').textContent;;
    const code = row.querySelector('.code').textContent;
    
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "update.php";
    const params = "link=" + encodeURIComponent(link) + "&priority=" + encodeURIComponent(priority) + "&code=" + encodeURIComponent(code);

  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhr.send(params);
```

[Here is the table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zawRv.png)

When I edit priority or link fields I want the `save` button to be shown. Then when I click the save button `saveRow` function should be ran. But I got following error on this line of code:

`const link = row.querySelector('.link').textContent;`
"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')"

What should I do?

I cut `saveRow` function context to paste in `showSaveButton` function but **it is  working.** but in `saveRow` function Not.

Comment: `this.parentElement` is not enough. The parent element of the `<button>` is the `<td>`, not the `<tr>`. Please use [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) instead. Regarding `onclick='deleteRow(" . $row["Code"] . ")'`, please see [Why are inline event handler attributes a bad idea in modern semantic HTML?](/q/11737873/4642212), and [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](/q/23740548/4642212). This _will_ fail, eventually.